# I want restore variable in localStorage without replacing existing variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i restore value in local storage please help me..??

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 )
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            if ( data.hasOwnProperty(username.value) && data[username.value]["pass"] === password.value){

                saveLocalstorage('task' , JSON.stringify(data[username.value]["task"]));
                if(window.localStorage){
                    location.pathname += "redirect_page.html";
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage));

                }else {
                    localStorage.clear();
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("user not available");
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('GET',"user.json",true);
    xhttp.send()
```

i want to restore value in "task" variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage.setItem`

```
localStorage.setItem('task' , JSON.stringify(data[username.value]["task"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to save in localStorage other than localStorage.setItem() is

```
localStorage.task = JSON.stringify(data[username.value]["task"]);
```

and you can retrieve the data as

```
localStorage.task;
```